# CHOICE in FOR loop - Windows Batch

Tags: batch-file

I have this loop that repeats itself for every line in an external file. I would like to prompt the user for a choice in every pass, though this doesn't work. I reckon the problem is with the GOTO command breaking the loop somehow. Any thoughts on this?

```
FOR /F %%i IN (%WORKDIR%\grunt-packages.ini) DO (
    CHOICE /C AN /M "Odinstalovat plugin"
    IF %ERRORLEVEL%==1 GOTO UNINSTALL
    IF %ERRORLEVEL%==2 GOTO SKIP

    :UNINSTALL
        ECHO Odstranuji %%i 
        CALL npm uninstall %%i

    :SKIP
        ECHO Preskakuji %%i
)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your reckoning is correct.  `goto` within for loops will stop the loop.  The way around this is to use `call` instead.  However, the first issue with your script is the need of delayed expansion for the `ERRORLEVEL` variable.  Whenever expanding variables that are set within a parentheses scope, use delayed expansion to get the latest value.

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
FOR /F %%i IN (%WORKDIR%\grunt-packages.ini) DO (
    CHOICE /C AN /M "Odinstalovat plugin"
    IF !ERRORLEVEL!==1 CALL :UNINSTALL
    IF !ERRORLEVEL!==2 CALL :SKIP
)
ENDLOCAL
GOTO :EOF

:UNINSTALL
    ECHO Odstranuji %%i 
    CALL npm uninstall %%i
    GOTO :EOF

:SKIP
    ECHO Preskakuji %%i
    GOTO :EOF
```

1. `goto` *cannot* be used within `for` loops.
2. Variables set within parentheses need delayed expansion to retrieve the new value. `!` instead of `%`. Otherwise, the value of the variable from before the parentheses scope will be used.

Answer (score 6):

@Metzger's answer was a good start (I up-voted it), but I found some problems with it. In the end, I prefer to put the code inline and avoid the `CALLs`. Here's my test code to show how it's done:

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
FOR %%i IN (A B C D) DO (
    CHOICE /C AN /M "Uninstall plugin %%i"
    IF !ERRORLEVEL!==1 (
        ECHO Uninstall %%i
    ) ELSE IF !ERRORLEVEL!==2 (
        ECHO Skip %%i
    )
)
```

I tested @Metzger's answer on Windows XP and found the following issues:

- Subroutines missing `GOTO :EOF` (already fixed)
- On Windows XP, in the subroutines `%%i` is unset
- (Potential bug) If uninstall sets `ERRORLEVEL`, SKIP might be called

This test code fixes the problems:

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
FOR %%i IN (A B C D) DO (
    CHOICE /C AN /M "Uninstall plugin %%i"
    SET OERRORLEVEL=!ERRORLEVEL!
    IF !ERRORLEVEL!==1 CALL :UNINSTALL %%i
    IF !OERRORLEVEL!==2 CALL :SKIP %%i
)
ENDLOCAL
GOTO :EOF

:UNINSTALL
    ECHO Uninstall %1
    GOTO :EOF

:SKIP
    ECHO Skip %1
    GOTO :EOF
```

Comment: +1 Those are Good points to note. **`:)`**  Especially, about ERRORLEVEL being possibly set in UNINSTALL.  I thought about mentioning passing `%%i` as a parameter, but figured it was not needed (works on 7 & 8 as is).

Answer (score 1):

This structure avoids the use of DELAYEDEXPANSION

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
FOR %%i IN (A B C D) DO (
SET destcall=BADCHOICE
choice /c QJ /M "%%i - choose Q or J"
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 SET destcall=CHOSEQ
IF ERRORLEVEL 2 SET destcall=CHOSEJ
CALL CALL :%%destcall%%
)
GOTO :eof

:badchoice
ECHO bad choice
GOTO :eof

:choseq
ECHO You chose Q
GOTO :eof

:chosej
ECHO You chose J
GOTO :eof
```